# Exception while trying to acquire a JMH lock

Tags: java, jmh

This code was working fine. On restarting the computer, it gives me the error:

```
ERROR: org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException: 
ERROR: Exception while trying to acquire the JMH lock (C:\WINDOWS\/jmh.lock): 
Access is denied, exiting. Use -Djmh.ignoreLock=true to forcefully continue.
at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:213)
at org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(Main.java:71)
```

Google-int the error didn't help. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class test {
    public ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> i = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>(10000);
    public ArrayList<String> k = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    public int p=0;

public void setup(){
    for(int m=0;m<1000;m++){
        int j=ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,10000);
        String jk=Integer.toString(j);
        k.add(jk);
        i.put(jk,j);
    }
}

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 3)
@Measurement(iterations = 5)
public void putKey(){
    int n=ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,10000);
    String nk=Integer.toString(n);
    k.add(nk);
    i.put(nk,n);
}

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 3)
@Measurement(iterations = 5)
public int getKey(){
    p=ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,10000);
    p=p%k.size();
    return i.get(k.get(p));
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException{
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(".*" + test.class.getSimpleName() + ".*")
            .forks(1)
            .build();
    new Runner(opt).run();
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have write permissions in your c drive windows folder?

Comment: @SauravSircar Did you try use `-Djmh.ignoreLock=true`? You can also look at this [post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2016-January/002122.html)

Comment: Have you tried do manually delete the ``C:\WINDOWS\/jmh.lock`` file ?

Comment: @KoustavRay How do I do that? Sorry I'm quite new at Java.

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis I'm unable to find it.

Comment: tried to show hidden files ?

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis Yup.

Comment: Note that the error says "access denied"

Comment: Try creating a new file in that same location

Answer (score 14):

There are 2 solutions:

- add the TMP environment variable in the plugin configuration and point it to any writeable directory.
  [image]
- run idea64.exe as Administrator

See https://github.com/artyushov/idea-jmh-plugin/issues/19

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error message using the Gradle (command-line) on Windows. (I needed to pass `--stacktrace` to find the root-cause error message.)

In my case it was due to the following issue:

https://github.com/artyushov/idea-jmh-plugin/issues/19

And the solution was simply to bump the version of the `jmh-gradle-plugin`. Minimum required versions are documented here:

https://github.com/melix/jmh-gradle-plugin